# Further termination check in agda, now with an indexed relation

Tags: functional-programming, agda, dependent-type, formal-verification

Suppose I have a Monoid A for some type A

Next, I have a datastructure indexed by this type.
It has nice recursive structure, however it is not 
something you would want to work with.

```
data F : A → Set where
  ...
```

Therefore, I construct this following the work of 
McKinna, the view from the left.

```
data V : A → Set where 
    nil : V ε 
    cons : ∀ {μ} → (x : A) → F μ → V (x ⊕ μ)
```

I can build a function

```
view : ∀ {μ} : F μ → V μ
```

What I want is implement a recursive function on F μ

```
f : ∀ {μ} : F μ → C μ (C could also be indexed) 
f fs with view fs 
f fs | nil = some value
f fs | cons x xs = op x (f xs)
Where op is some arbitrary operation.
```

This obviously fails the termination check, which is why I am posting this question

I have seen previous answers related to definind well founded induction on 
natural numbers, as well an idea to generalize it to a multiple arity function.

However, the standard library doesn't work with indexed relations.

Trying to write an operator like this:

```
data _<_ {μ x σ} : F σ → F μ → Set 
   <-cons: ∀ (f : F μ) → (g : F σ) → (view f ≡ cons x g) → (g < f)
```

Doesn't even type check because f has type F μ not type F (x ⊕ σ)

Supposing I could prove that this relation is well founded.   (it is not in this case because I can get an infinite chain ε ⊕ ε ⊕ ε ⊕ ..  where ε is the neutral element for my monoid,
  but I am looking for a general framework where I can do such proofs)

I have excluded the instance argument of the monoid for simplicity here.

I got stuck with this in my dissertation, would really appreciate some help.
Thank you very much!
Also first post on stack overflow, so please let me know if any clarification is needed.

Comment: What do you achieve by this `V`? Normally, a view is a way to look inside some type, here it's `A`, but you seem to be unsatisfied by structural recursion that `F` provides, but `V` doesn't improve anything related to `F`. The question would be much clearer if you provide more details on what `F` is and why it's not something you would want to work with.

Comment: Essentially, F is a nested datatype and V is trying to flatten it. I will edit the post in the afternoon. Thanks for the reply :)